# form with 2 radios for each user in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, foreach

I have a form that dynamically prints out names based on a unique name tag. 
To be used for responding on invitations. There can be multiple users for each name tag, i.e. couples, couples with children, etc.
For each name there is a radio-button where the invitee can select whether he/she is coming to the party or not (has the value 1=not coming, 2=coming). It can look like this, for a couple:

```
Lady Mary S
I am not coming         - radio - value 1
I am coming             - radio - value 2

Mister Hans S
I am not coming         - radio - value 1
I am coming             - radio - value 2

Child of Mary & Hans S
I am not coming         - radio - value 1
I am coming             - radio - value 2
```

Each of these invitees has a user id - I need the reponse to be with the user id. 
The HTML for it looks like this:

```
<div>
<h1>Lady Mary S</h1>
<label for="no-1">I am not coming</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" id="no-1" name="response[1]" /><br />
<label for="yes-1">I am coming</label> 
<input type="radio" value="2" id="yes-1" name="response[1]" />
<input type="hidden" name="userid[]" value="1" />
</div>

<div>
<h1>Mister Hans S</h1>
<label for="no-2">I am not coming</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" id="no-2" name="response[2]" /><br />
<label for="yes-2">I am coming</label> 
<input type="radio" value="2" id="yes-2" name="response[2]" />
<input type="hidden" name="userid[]" value="2" />
</div>

<div>
<h1>Child of Mary & Hans S</h1>

<label for="no-3">I am not coming</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" id="no-3" name="response[3]" /><br />
<label for="yes-3">I am coming</label> 
<input type="radio" value="2" id="yes-3" name="response[3]" />
<input type="hidden" name="userid[]" value="3" />
</div>
```

These names will be fetched from MySQL with a unique nametag for these 3 people, f.x. `MARHAN`

This is a dynamic form - for some nametags there will only be two invitees and for other nametags there will be 3 or 4, etc.

My problems is that I cannot come up with a solution on how to handle the posted data so I can make sure the reponse is for the right user id.

Comment: good idea to have `name="response[userid value][]"`

Comment: Arh .. sorry! I already have that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
foreach($_POST['response'] as $userid => $value) {
      echo $userid.'-'.$value."<br>";
}
```

Because you already have `userid in key` of radio button name `name="response[1]"`

Comment: Very very simple! Must be why I couldn't see it! :) Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: How about making the value of each input something like 'answer-userId'. e.g.:

```
<input type="radio" value="1-333" id="no-3" name="response[]" /><br />
```

Then you can split the posted value in php by '-' and get the answer (1) and user id (333).